# FFmpeg black screen using mpeg2video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters

I have a proprietary piece of hardware for broadcasting, that accepts extremely specific video format.
The software that we use for it is extremely slow and outdated.

I was looking at adapting FFmpeg to convert .avi/.mp4/etc to the specific format which in our case is

> .mpg ( 720*576 16:9, 25FPS, MPEG Video PAL v.2 (Main@High) BVOP)
>   acceptable bitrate is  9000k - 15000k.

So I have constructed this FFmpeg command:

`-i input.avi -codec:a mp2 -b:a 384k -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 16:9 -bf 2 -b:v 10000k -maxrate 10000k -minrate 10000k -bufsize 5000k  -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 output.mpg`

The audio is working fine, but instead of video I get a black screen, this is the conversion log

```
"E:\auto_video\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i input.avi -codec:a mp2 -b:a 384k -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 16:9 -bf 2 -b:v 10000k -maxrate 10000k -minrate 10000k -bufsize 5000k -r 25  -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 output.mpg
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-12-38737b3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 54.100 / 56. 54.100
  libavcodec     58. 92.100 / 58. 92.100
  libavformat    58. 46.101 / 58. 46.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020-06-04T14:11:03+06:00
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30465 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 28915 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
File 'output.mpg' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpeg, to 'output.mpg':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020-06-04T14:11:03+06:00
    encoder         : Lavf58.46.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 10000 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.92.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 10000000/10000000/10000000 buffer size: 5000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.92.100 mp2
frame=  250 fps=0.0 q=2.5 Lsize=   12574kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=10302.7kbits/s speed=16.8x
video:12054kB audio:469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.402694%"E:\auto_video\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i input.avi -codec:a mp2 -b:a 384k -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 16:9 -bf 2 -b:v 10000k -maxrate 10000k -minrate 10000k -bufsize 5000k -r 25  -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 output.mpg
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-12-38737b3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 54.100 / 56. 54.100
  libavcodec     58. 92.100 / 58. 92.100
  libavformat    58. 46.101 / 58. 46.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'input.avi':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020-06-04T14:11:03+06:00
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 30465 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo (dvsd / 0x64737664), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 28915 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
File 'output.mpg' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mpeg, to 'output.mpg':
  Metadata:
    date            : 2020-06-04T14:11:03+06:00
    encoder         : Lavf58.46.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 10000 kb/s, 25 fps, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.92.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 10000000/10000000/10000000 buffer size: 5000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.92.100 mp2
frame=  250 fps=0.0 q=2.5 Lsize=   12574kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=10302.7kbits/s speed=16.8x
video:12054kB audio:469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.402694%
```

Additional info that might help, I get black screen in MPC-HC, Windows Media Player, and the actual hardware that I converted it for. But it plays fine in VLC

Comment: Can you show info for a file that does work on the picky hardware? The output of `ffmpeg -i input.mpg` will suffice.

Comment: Input #0, mpeg, from 'U:\PL_cyberdays_10.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:10.06, start: 0.377133, bitrate: 11367 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, bottom first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 18500000/0/0 buffer size: 7716864 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s

Comment: Why don't you try giving ffmpeg some freedom in terms of bitrate: `-b:v 10000k -maxrate 15000k -minrate 9000k`?

Comment: Still getting black screen as the output, but thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: Side note: -i in.avi -c:v mpeg2video out.mpg - this gives black screen as well

Comment: Try: **1.** Download stable version of `FFmpeg` instead of nightly build. **2.** Create synthetic video using the command: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=5:size=720x576:rate=25 -c:v mpeg2video -aspect 16:9 -bf 2 -b:v 10000k -maxrate 10000k -minrate 10000k -bufsize 5000k output.mpg` **3.** Update video codecs (for MPC-HC). You may install `K-Lite Codec Pack`.

Comment: Tried 4.3.2 stable, the artificial video results in black screen.
Replacing Haali and LAV Filter with K-Lite did work on the pc though.
Still doesn't work on hardware, the thing is, while using the proprietary converter I could view the video with any player, so it was not a codec issue.

Side issue: -profile:v main -level:v 4.0 doesent work on stable release for some reason - "Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'main'"